# SQL Server 2012 memory use is 1000 x size of database - is this right?

Tags: sql-server

I understand from a search here that SQL Server 2012 will continue to use memory until it meets the limit set for it, but the usage I see is hard to believe. The database is about 26MB at the moment, but the memory usage is over 30GB. Is this to be expected or is there some other problem lurking somewhere?

Comment: Is that database the only one that's ever been attached to the server? Is the database only ever been 26 MB? Has someone, at some time, ever run an incredibly stupid recursive query that blew up data ad infinitum? Is SQL Server configured to use a set minimum in the options? But maybe more to the point, have you heard about the wonders of `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`? (Especially look at the free page indicator.) If you really think the usage is "in error" (it's probably not) you can always restart the engine and see what happens. Pay attention to the error log when you do.

Comment: Where **exactly** did you observe this "memory usage"?

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. The database is the only one that has ever been on the server, The database has never been larger. I don't think any recursive queries have been run. There is no minimum memory usage (it is 0). I did a restart and the memory dropped down into the hundreds of MB. It is going up but quite slowly, 30MB in several hours, so how it got to 30GB in a few days is beyond me? I didn't know about DBCC MEMORYSTATUS but I will check it next time and post here if it happens again. I observed the memory using task manager, and I'm pretty sure it has never done this before.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. The memory allocated to SQL Server can be changed to almost any value you'd like. I'd say 30GB is certainly overkill for a 26MB DB if it is the only DB on the instance. The memory allocated to SQL Server is used for numerous functions, e.g. sorting queries, plan caches, etc. The 30GB you're seeing means that 30GB of your system memory is reserved for SQL Server.

For a better understanding, you'll want to look into your target memory too. Target memory is how much memory is needed for SQL Server work, based on your configuration. In your case, I bet target memory equals max memory and SQL Server is trying to consume all the memory. Here is how you can check that:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name in ('Total Server Memory (KB)', 'Target Server Memory (KB)')
```

More information from Brent Ozar:

> So how much memory is SQL using?  I’ll make this easy for you. SQL
>   Server is using all of the memory. Period.
>
> No matter how much memory you put in a system, SQL Server will use all
>   it can get until it’s caching entire databases in memory and then
>   some.  This isn’t an accident, and there’s a good reason for it.  SQL
>   Server is a database: programmers store data in SQL Server, and then
>   SQL Server manages writing that data to files on the hard drive. 
>   Programmers issue SELECT statements (yes, usually SELECT *) and SQL
>   Server fetches the data back from the drives.  The organization of
>   files and drives is abstracted away from the programmers.
>
> To improve performance, SQL Server caches data in memory.  SQL Server
>   doesn’t have a shared-disk model: only one server’s SQLserver.exe can
>   touch the data files at any given time.  SQL Server knows that once it
>   reads a piece of data from the drives, that data isn’t changing unless
>   SQL Server itself needs to update it.  Data can be read into memory
>   once and safely kept around forever.  And I do mean forever – as long
>   as SQL Server’s up, it can keep that same data in memory.  If you have
>   a server with enough memory to cache the entire database, SQL Server
>   will do just that. Why Doesn’t SQL Server Release Memory?
>
> Memory makes up for a lot of database sins like:
>
> ```
> Slow, cheap storage (like SATA hard drives and 1Gb iSCSI)
> Programs that needlessly retrieve too much data
> Databases that don’t have good indexes
> CPUs that can’t build query plans fast enough
> ```
>
> Throw enough memory at these problems and they go away, so SQL Server
>   wants to use all the memory it can get. It also assumes that more
>   queries could come in at any moment, so it never lets go or releases
>   memory unless the server comes under memory pressure (like if other
>   apps need memory and Windows sends out a memory pressure
>   notification).
>
> By default, SQL Server assumes that its server exists for the sole
>   purpose of hosting databases, so the default setting for memory is an
>   unlimited maximum.  (There are some version/edition restrictions, but
>   let’s keep things simple for now.)  This is a good thing; it means the
>   default setting is covering up for sins.  To find out if the server’s
>   memory is effectively covering up sins, we have to do some
>   investigation.

Docs on SQL Server memory configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options

Here is how you can set a fixed amount for Min/Max memory on SQL Server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144(v=sql.105).aspx